# Explain Meteor.js as a Native Android App

Tags: android, node.js, meteor

I have a couple of questions I've tried to google, but can't seem to find a real explanation.

I'm currently developing in node.js (the MEAN stack). I've looked at some Meteor.js content and it's spiked my interest. I'm just curious about a couple things though, as I've read that Meteor can be an android app, even to the point it appears in the Google Play and the App Store. My questions are below:

1.) Is it a true native app and can Meteor access android APIs like the camera, bluetooth, WiFi module, GPS or file system?

2.) Can Meteor use Android's SQLite database?

3.) Is Meteor actually a `WebView` in an encapsulated Android app?

Thanks for any answers to this, as I'm just wondering if it's an app copycat without the same functionality or if it's a realistic way of creating an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Meteor can't really build native like apps. But it does really can access the camera, WiFi etc modules. The magic behind this is Cordova.

Meteor cannot directly user SQLite feature of Android. Cordova have additional plugins that help you make the workaround.

Meteor is definitely not a WebView as it uses the Mechanism of Cordova.

Just to let you that, In order to have an app working properly with the database, you need to have a real Meteor server hosted somewhere and point that `url` when building the apk. And Meteor has an awesome feature called hot code push, which reduces the task of rebuilding the apk again & again. If your Meteor server is updated, so does the APK. No need to submit again in play store.